# product of max inequality

Tags: inequality, vectors, normed-spaces

Given $m$ vectors $x_{i| i=1\cdots m}$ and $y_{i| i=1\cdots m}$.
Is there any inequality relationship between the max of the product of the square of $\ell_2$ norm of $m$ vectors and the product of the max of the square of $\ell_2$ norm of $m$ vectors i.e

Is there a relationship exist

$$
\max_{i} x_ix'_i \max_j y_jy'_j \leq \max_i x_ix'_iy_iy'_i
$$ here $x'_i$ is the transpose of vector $x_i$.

if so, can anyone give me a proof

Comment: Isn't $x_iy_i$ the dot product of vectors? In that case, by $||x_iy_i||$ do you mean the absolute value?

Comment: What do you mean by $x_i y_i$? If you mean the dot product of those vectors, then select $x_i \perp y_i$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: @Macavity   corrected the question to get rid of the inconsistency in notation.

Comment: @Javi  corrected the question.

Comment: In the new version of your question, vectors are irrelevant, you may replace each $xx’$ with any nonnegative number. Hence it is obvious the reverse inequality holds true.

Comment: @Macavity, yes, in fact the vector is irrelevant. Can you give me the proof so that I can accept it as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_i=x_ix_i’$ and $b_i=y_iy_i’$. Then $a_i,b_i$ are non-negative reals and we may show
$$\max a_i \max b_i \geqslant \max a_ib_i$$

One way to see this is to plot $a_i$ and $b_i$ on the Cartesian plane. The LHS is the largest rectangle (by area) while RHS represents the area of a rectangle contained within it. Equality is possible when the same $i$ maximises $a_i$ and $b_i$ simultaneously.